# How to getLocation after enable GPS from ResolvableApiException(Google services) dialog

Tags: android, google-location-services

I am using google service for getting the current location.

I am using this method for enabling location:

```
void enableLoc(Activity activity, int request) {

    LocationRequest mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(10000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

    LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
            .addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);


    SettingsClient client = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(activity);
    Task<LocationSettingsResponse> task = client.checkLocationSettings(builder.build());

    task.addOnSuccessListener(activity, locationSettingsResponse -> {
        if (locationSettingsResponse.getLocationSettingsStates().isGpsUsable())
            onGetLocation(activity);
    });

    task.addOnFailureListener(activity, e -> {
        if (e instanceof ResolvableApiException) {
            try {

                Timber.d("Dialog to allow GPS location");
                // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                ResolvableApiException resolvable = (ResolvableApiException) e;
                resolvable.startResolutionForResult(activity,
                        request);
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException sendEx) {
                // Ignore the error.
            }
        }
    });

}
```

I am getting Location From:

```
@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
 void onGetLocation(Activity activity) {
    FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(activity);
    fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(location -> {

        //I am getting Null after enabling GPS Location

    });
}
```

This is my onActivityResult method:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        onGetLocation(this);
    }
}
```

I am getting Null Location after enabling GPS Location.

Answer (score 0):

used below class ...

```
public class LocationActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private static final int REQUEST_LOCATION = 1;

    Button button;
    TextView textView;
    LocationManager locationManager;
    String lattitude, longitude;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.location_layout);

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_LOCATION);

        textView = findViewById(R.id.text_location);
        button = findViewById(R.id.button_location);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            buildAlertMessageNoGps();

        } else if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            getLocation();
        }
    }


    private void getLocation() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission
                (this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_LOCATION);

        } else {
            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            Location location1 = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            Location location2 = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER);

            if (location != null) {
                double latti = location.getLatitude();
                double longi = location.getLongitude();
                lattitude = String.valueOf(latti);
                longitude = String.valueOf(longi);

                textView.setText("Your current location is" + "\n" + "Lattitude = " + lattitude
                        + "\n" + "Longitude = " + longitude);

            } else if (location1 != null) {
                double latti = location1.getLatitude();
                double longi = location1.getLongitude();
                lattitude = String.valueOf(latti);
                longitude = String.valueOf(longi);

                textView.setText("Your current location is" + "\n" + "Lattitude = " + lattitude
                        + "\n" + "Longitude = " + longitude);


            } else if (location2 != null) {
                double latti = location2.getLatitude();
                double longi = location2.getLongitude();
                lattitude = String.valueOf(latti);
                longitude = String.valueOf(longi);

                textView.setText("Your current location is" + "\n" + "Lattitude = " + lattitude
                        + "\n" + "Longitude = " + longitude);
                String url = "https://iradivi.com/test/?latitude=" + lattitude + "&longitude=" + longitude;


            } else {

                Toast.makeText(this, "Unble to Trace your location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
    }

    protected void buildAlertMessageNoGps() {

        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("Please Turn ON your GPS Connection")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int id) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }

}
```

add add follwing dependency in manifest file..

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```